# How to draw the normals at many points in a surface?

Tags: matlab, vector, plot, draw, normals

`X,Y and Z` are the matrices contain the coordinates of points in the surface.
`Xnormal,Ynormal and Znormal` are the matrices contain the normals at these points.
How can I draw all these normals at their position?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/quiver3.html) Mathworks documentation for the `quiver3` command.

Comment: Please "accept" answers you find correct (press the check mark next to the answers that satisfies you). This is one of the ways to build up your reputation on Stackoverflow.